# Putting an ImageButton below a ScrollView in android layout activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-scrollview, android-imagebutton

I am trying to put this image button at the bottom of the screen, but nothing appears. above it is the ScrollView text. How can I put this imagebutton below it ? Thanks.

```
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_SKMM"
            android:src="@drawable/skmmlogo"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Here is my activity layout xml file, you can check btn_SKMM is at the last LinearLayout but that didnt appear on the device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_ActionTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Privacy Policy"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_margin="15sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/btn_Close"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_x="0px"
                android:layout_y="25dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10sp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fbedittext"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/fbedittext"
                    android:text="" />
            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_SKMM"
                android:src="@drawable/skmmlogo"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

UPDATE: this seems to fix it, just additional if can help, trying to put the text(txt_sometext) next to imagebutton(btn_SKMM), the text(txt_sometext) doesnt appear. Thanks

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_x="0px"
            android:layout_y="25dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10sp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fbedittext"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fbedittext"
                android:text="" />
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_SKMM"
                android:src="@drawable/skmmlogo"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="sometext"
                android:id="@+id/txt_sometext"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The second inner `LinearLayout` is taking up all the space remaining after the first. Change the second's `layout_height` to `0dp`, and set its `layout_weight` to `1`.

Comment: Also, the last two inner `LinearLayout`s aren't necessary, if they're just going to hold one `View` each. You can remove them, and set the necessary `layout_*` attributes on the `ScrollView` and `ImageButton`.

Comment: thanks @MikeM., that fixes it, if you can help a bit more, im trying to put some text next to the imagebutton. txt_sometext. can you see the updated fix ? thanks.

Comment: In the layout you just added, you have the background of the outer `LinearLayout` set to white, and you have the `textColor` of your `TextView` set to white, as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ok wrong settings!